# Any way to get email address from Google Drive API Permissions so I can differentiate 2 users with the same name?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have read from previous posts [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635372/drive-api-external-sharing), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846293/value-attribute-for-permissions-resource-not-populated-in-responses), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240253/permissions-access)] that the email address is not displayed for Google Drive Permissions API due to privacy reasons. But I am trying to look for a way to display user permissions where there are 2 different users with the same name.

With the Google Drive sharing UI, you can differentiate two different users with the same name as it also displays their email next to their name (I don't see why this is not possible in the API if the Google Drive UI can get it).

I would prefer not having to rely on the now deprecated DocList API to get the emails from the ACLs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, using the documents list API is your only option for now to get the email addresses, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ali, any idea if this may be supported in the future? (i.e. will some workaround be available in later Drive API version?)

Comment: Defeinitely looking to get a solution for this.

Comment: because of this I can't distinguish between users so I can delete them...why can we add permissions by email but cannot delete by email

Comment: @NycCompSci see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410934/cannot-find-id-of-owner-of-a-file-shared-with-me

Comment: @AliAfshar i realize email addresses cannot be trivially disclosed, but at least the opaque user-id should be available. it is available under the absolute minimum oauth scopes supported by google, so no reason why you should use the name of the user instead of the opaque user id. it is the worst of both worlds -- it is not opaque so it leaks privacy and it is not unique so useless for engineering. this is re question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410934/cannot-find-id-of-owner-of-a-file-shared-with-me

Comment: Hey Ali, in light of the new email address changes presented by Steven Bazyl on Google Developers live, would it make sense to update to this answer?

Answer (score 5):

With v3 API yu can specify the fields parameter of your request.

For Get request : `request.Fields = "kind,id,type,emailAddress,domain,role,allowFileDiscovery,displayName,photoLink,expirationTime,teamDrivePermissionDetails,deleted"`

For List request : `request.Fields = "permissions(kind,id,type,emailAddress,domain,role,allowFileDiscovery,displayName,photoLink,expirationTime,teamDrivePermissionDetails,deleted)"`

Comment: You can also just use an asterisk (`*`).

Comment: @OlegVaskevich Nice, I did not know that, where is that documented?

Comment: Dany: see https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance#partial

Comment: "Use wildcards in field selections, if needed.
For example: fields=items/pagemap/* selects all objects in a pagemap."

Answer (score 1):

```
About about = service.about().get().execute();
User user = about.getUser();            
System.out.println("user" + user.toString());
```

You can print out the user information (JSON string).
It contains the emailAddress.

You can parse the JSON string for the emailAddress.

Answer (score 0):

`list` does not return email, but `get` does

```
permission = service.permissions.get(fileId,permissionId)
System.out.println("email" + permission.emailAddress);
```