# Cannot find id of owner of a file shared with me

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Using the Google Drive API: `drive.changes.list` I get a list of files for a user including those shared by another user. For the files that are owned by another user only the owner's name is shown in the API. Naturally names are not unique and the owner can change it on a whim, so pretty useless for correlating that the owner of two different shared files is the same.

How can I get the unique id of the owner? Is this possible?

Is there a reason this is not allowed? It seems un-engineer-like to disclose the name of the owner but not an opaque id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owners[].permissionId attribute as described by the [files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) should be unique across all of a given users files. So if the owner permissionId is the same for two files, then the file is owned by the same account.

It's currently not possible to retrieve the email address of owners or document collaborators though [there are plans to remedy this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148021/any-way-to-get-email-address-from-google-drive-api-permissions-so-i-can-differen).

Comment: email address is not needed. assuming the permissionid uniqueness is indeed guaranteed, this is good enough. in general though if the necessary oauth permission is available then there should be a way to lookup the email address, and to do so there should be a way to look up owner id from permissionid. thanks for your answer!